# Tomcat script not working when run from Hudson

Tags: linux, tomcat, hudson, jenkins

I'm trying to run a script which stops and starts Tomcat on linux.

When I run it from the command line it works fine. But it does not seem to work when I run the same script from the "Execute Shell" build step in a Jenkins/Hudson job. Jenkins doesn't report any errors but if I try going to the tomcat page then I get a page not found error.

So Jenkins seems able to stop the server, but not bringing it back up.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: What error do you get *exactly*? Is it a 404? Or "connection refused"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try unsetting the BUILD_ID in your 'shell execute' block. You might even not need to use `nohup` in this case

```
BUILD_ID=
./your_hudson_script_that_starts_tomcat.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like changing the BUILD_ID fixed it. Although I couldn't quite get your example to work so I tried this [link](http://www.tikalk.com/alm/starting-tomcat-part-build-process-with-hudson-ci-0) which seems to do the trick.

Comment: Hey, could u explain about what BUILD_ID means here? I'm not quite understand. Many thanks :]

Comment: BUILD_ID is an environment variable set by Jenkins which is available to the process that's spawned by the jenkins build job. Here are some details why unsetting BUILD_ID keeps the spawned process running: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Comment: @Bernhard : Many thanks for your solution, it helped a newbie who's facing the same issue :) but I don't understand the rationale behind it.. 
what has build_id to do with starting up of tomcat or any script ? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your script it is difficult to give an exact answer. However you could try adding the following to the start of your script (assuming it is a bash script):

```
# Trace executed commands.
set -x

# Save stdout / stderr in files
exec >/tmp/my_script.stdout
exec 2>/tmp/my_script.stderr
```

You could also try adding

```
set -e
```

to make the shell exit immediately if a command returns an error status.

If it looks as though Hudson is killing off Tomcat then you might want to run it within nohup (if you're not already doing that):

```
nohup bin/startup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: If I put a long sleep in then try to go to the tomcat page, it appears OK until the job completes. So I was wondering whether Jenkins automatically kills any processes it started, when a job completes.

Comment: I'ved added a bit about nohup to my answer above (can't format code within this comment). Hopefully that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I created a new script with the nohup call like you said: `nohup /usr/tomcat5/bin/startup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &` which I got my Jenkins instance to call, but it still doesn't seem to work. Although it does work OK when I run the script manually.